# Username button dropdown content not displayed properly

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsp

I have a following code which has username button at the top. When i click on the username button, a dropdown with some data would be usually displayed.

Here is the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style>
body{
    background-color:#A9D18E;
}

.split {

  height: 89%;
  width: 70%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  padding-top: 20px;
  top: 50px;

  
}

.left {
position: absolute;
  left: 360px; /* Initial value is 260 */
  background-color: #A9D18E;
  border-left: 5px solid black;


  
}

.right {
  right: 0;
  background-color: #A9D18E;

}
.button1{
float:right;
position:relative;
top:4px;
width: 120px;
height: 25px;
}

.border{
border-style:solid;
position:relative;
top:35px;
}

.centeredright {
position: relative;
top: 180px;
right: -170px;
width: 500px;
border: 2px solid;
}

.centeredleft {
position: relative;
right: 260px;
border: 1px solid;
width: 100px;
height: 50px;
background-color: white;
}

.back {
  background-color: #002060;
  text-align: right;
  color: white;
  padding: 11px 6px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: relative;
  right: 320px;
  top: 410px;
}

.esummary {
  background-color: #6666FF;
  text-align: right;
  color: white;
  padding: 11px 6px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: relative;
   right: 320px;
  top: 410px;
}


.next {
  background-color: #002060;
  text-align: right;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: relative;
  left: 850px;
  top: 305px;
  
}

/*::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 1px;
    height: 300px;
}*/
.table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
  right: 60px;

 height:400px;
 width:300px;
 overflow-y:auto;

}

td {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 10px;
}


 .dropdown-content {
              display: none;
              position: absolute;
              background-color: pink;
              color: black;
              min-width: 30px;
              box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
              padding: 12px 16px;
              z-index: 1;
        }

        .dropdown-content.show {
            display: block;
            position: absolute;
            right:1%;
        }

        .dropdown-content a {
              display: block;
              margin-bottom: 8px;
              color: black;
              text-decoration: none;
        }

        .dropdown-content a:last-child {
            margin-bottom: 0;
        }

        .dropdown-content a:hover {
            background-color: #f1f1f1;
        }
.add_vuln_button{
    
     background-color: #6666FF;
  text-align: right;
  color: white;
  padding: 11px 6px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: relative;
   right: 350px;
  top: 520px;

}
</style>

<script>
function toggleDropdown() {
      var dropdownContent = document.getElementById("dropdownContent");
      dropdownContent.classList.toggle("show");
    }

</script>
</head>
<body>
<button type="button" class="button1" onclick="toggleDropdown()">Username <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i> </button>
        <div class="dropdown-content" id="dropdownContent">
                <a href="myprofile.jsp">My Profile</a>
                <a href="docs.jsp">Documents</a>
                <a href="logout.jsp">Logout</a>
    </div>
    
    
<div class="border"></div>
<div class="split left">
  <div class="centeredleft">
    <p>Vulnerabilities</p>
    <div class="table">

    
    <%
    StringBuilder tableRows = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 1; i <= 35; i++) {
        String tableRow = "<tr>" +
                "<td>" + i + "</td>" +
                "<td>Vulnerability" + i + "</td>" +
                "<td><input type=\"checkbox\" id=\"vul" + i + "\" name=\"vul" + i + "\">" +
                "<label for=\"vul" + i + "\">Edit</label><br></td>" +
                "</tr>";

        tableRows.append(tableRow);
    }
%>

<!-- Output the table rows -->
<table>
    <%= tableRows.toString() %>
</table>

  </div>    
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="back" style="background-color:#002060;" onclick="window.location.href = 'main_page.jsp';">Back to Home Page</button>
  <button type="button" class="esummary" style="background-color:#6666FF;" onclick="window.location.href = 'application_security_posture.jsp';">Executive Summary</button>
</div>

<div class="split right">

  <button type="button" class="add_vuln_button">Add Vulnerability</button>
</div>
     
</body>
</html>
```

But in this above code, when i click on the username button, the dropdown data is not displayed properly. I am new to web application development and any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.